# How to run tests after server is up

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Trying to create a GitLab-CI config, which should start a Python server and run some tests afterwards.

So far, I've managed to fetch the right image and the server comes up. But afterwards, the script is stuck and I have no idea on how to jump to the next one.

My **gitlab-ci.yml**

```
build:
  image: python:3.7.9
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - python3 server.py

test:
  script:
    - python3 -m unittest discover tests
```

So, basically 2 stages; build should set up the server and test should run some unit tests. I am aware that these 2 jobs are independent from each other - once the stages are configured correctly, I'll change it.

Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you must run your server and your test in the same job. A common way of doing this is to 'background' your server. We often do this by ending a line in bash with an ampersand `&`

So your configuration might look like this:

```yaml
test:
  image: python:3.7.9
  before_script:
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - echo "starting the server"
    - python3 server.py &
    - sleep 1 # give the server a moment to start
    - python3 -m unittest discover tests
```

Additionally, you might consider having your test suite setup the test server so that's all encapsulated with your test runner. Then you don't have to worry about these things being separate steps at all.

For example, many Python web frameworks have their own test helpers that will create the test application for you as part of the setup for *every* test case. This might become more important, for example, if your tests interact with a database and you need those test cases to be isolated.

Comment: thx a lot, I'm gonna try this out now :)

Answer (score 0):

you can run integration tests from within your test suites through testcontainers.

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python

it might be overkill, for start i would suggest the answer above by sytech